# Do hidden GET request in Javascript / Dojo?

Tags: javascript, post, dojo, get

I am pretty new to web development and had a pretty basic question (I think).

I want to do a GET request from my Javascript / DOJO code to hit a page and acquire a cookie before any other code. So far, to do a POST in the same code later, I have this code which works:

```
var form = domConstruct.create("form");
form.action = <url i'm posting to>;
form.method = "POST";
form.target = "_blank";

form.style.display = "none"; 
dojo.body().appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

The above code works exactly how I want it to. Now I want something similar as a GET request, but I don't want it to show up to the end-user at all. (The post code opens a new URL with the result of the POST to that URL). I tried replacing the "POST" with a "GET" and changing the form target but don't have it quite right. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use an invisible iframe to load the form to? Or just use ajax!

Comment: "Hidden" requests in Javascript are called XHR or Ajax. Check out the Dojo tutorial: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/ajax/